# How to single out root user from other users in script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a script in which I have to enforce different policies for different users. I am new to scripting how would I differentiate root user and normal user in script. This script should enforce policies differently for root user and normal user. Should I use regular expression to directly match the root keyword or is there any other way

Comment: can you give more explanation of what exactly you want to try? By the way, the root user will always have id =  0 ( use id command). Use this in your script.

Comment: thanks sunil. I am writing a script to list all the users of the system and then apply a password policy on every user except root user.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, the root user has a uid of 0.

You can check the (numeric) uid of the user running a script with `id -u` - if the return value is 0, you are root, otherwise, you are not.